# Pandas Mixed Type to Integer

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'A':['A','B','C','D'],
         'C':['1','12','*','8']
        })
df

    A   C
0   A   1
1   B   12
2   C   *
3   D   8
```

I'd like to remove all instances of '*' and convert the rest to integer.
There may be some instances of 'nan' or 'NaN' in my actual data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `pd.to_numeric` to convert the `C` column to numeric values. Passing `errors='coerce`' tells `pd.to_numeric` to set non-numeric values to `NaN`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'A':['A','B','C','D'],
         'C':['1','12','*','8'] })

df['C'] = pd.to_numeric(df['C'], errors='coerce')
print(df)
```

prints

```
   A     C
0  A   1.0
1  B  12.0
2  C   NaN
3  D   8.0
```

Since NaN values are only allowed in columns with floating-point dtype (or `object` dtype), the column can not be set to an integer dtype.

Answer (score 1):

int() is the Python standard built-in function to convert a string into an integer value. Convert the column to int using int().

For parsing integers instead of floats, you can use the isdigit() function for string objects.

If you run isdigit() after int(), you can filter the data to rows where the value for column C is an integer.