# pandas columns containing multiple data types

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel that I am importing into a pandas data frame. One of the columns has multiple data types after importing. The excel column has custom formatting (## ??/??") causing a float input to be represented as architectural format. Ex. 1.25 is displayed as 1 1/4" in excel. The blank cells in excel may not actually be blank. They may contain only spaces causing pandas to read it in as a str instead of Nan.

[image: excel]
[image: pandas data]
[image: pandas data type]

I need to perform some math functions against the 'float' and 'int' values in this column. I can't seem to determine a way to specify an "if data type 'float' or 'int' perform this math, else next"

```
dfc8['C17'] = ((dfc8['C17'] / 100).astype(int) * 12) + (((dfc8['C17'] / 100),
- (dfc8['C17'] / 100).astype(int)) * 100)
```

I have tried:

```
dfc8['C15'].str.strip()    
dfc8['C15'].astype(str).astype(float)
```

in various forms to convert the column to a single data type with no luck. Any guidance would help. Thanks.

```
df8 = [pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=s, skiprows=4, nrows=32, usecols='M:AA', header=None) for s in bolt]
# merge above data into a single sheet
dfc8 = pd.concat(df8, ignore_index=True, sort=False) if len(bolt) >= 2 else pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(df8, (32, 15)))
# rename column index numbers
dfc8.columns = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10', 'C11',
                'C12', 'C13', 'C14', 'C15']
# if column C contains a zero remove the row
dfc8 = dfc8[dfc8.C3 != 0]
```

Comment: `pd.to_numeric(dfc8['C15'], errors='coerce')`?

Comment: @BigBen I added that, and it still returned the same data types. I have added my code on how the data was imported, incase there is something that can be changed in it. Thanks.

Comment: Did you use `dfc3['C15'] = pd.to_numeric(dfc8['C15'], errors='coerce')`?

Comment: @BigBen Thanks. Was just about to reply that I forgot to assign it. That does change the data type for the entire column to float. So now there is a new error. "Cannot convert non-finite values (Na or inf) to integer". When it gets to the math function trying to use .astype(int).

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html I think

Comment: @BigBen Thanks. I'll get to reading. Since your suggestion did solve the original question, if you could submit it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate anyway, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146482/pandas-mixed-type-to-integer) for example. If you want you can self-answer.